# Probability question with two independent (binomial) groups

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

A study is being conducted in which the health of two independent groups of ten
policyholders is being monitored over a one-year period of time. Individual participants
in the study drop out before the end of the study with probability $0.2$ (independently of
the other participants).
Calculate the probability that at least nine participants complete the study in one of the
two groups, but not in both groups.

I set up a binomial model for each group where $X_i \sim B(10, 0.8)$ and then calculated $P[X_1 >= 9] + P[X_2 >= 9] - P[X_1 >=9] * P[X_2 >= 9]$, but it was incorrect. I thought this accounts for the given event, since I am subtracting off the probability of both groups having more than 9 completions. I'd appreciate it if someone tells me exactly why my method is wrong.

Comment: Use `\ge` to get $\ge$. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $~P~$ denote the probability that there are at least $~9~$ left, in a specific group.

Let $~Q = 1 - P.$

Then, the desired computation is

$$PQ + QP = 2PQ.$$

So, the problem reduces to computing $~P.$

$$P = ~\left[ ~\binom{10}{0}(0.2)^{0}(0.8)^{10 - 0}~\right] + ~\left[ ~\binom{10}{1}(0.2)^{1}(0.8)^{10 - 1}~\right].$$

---

$\underline{\text{Where you went wrong}}$

Your computation, using my variables, represents

$$2P - P^2.$$

What you actually want is

$$2PQ = 2P(1-P) = 2P - 2P^2.$$

Your answer, which is similar to an Inclusion-Exclusion computation counts the intersection twice, and then deducts it once.  This isn't what you want, since you must exclude the intersection, not count it once.

Comment: I understand, but what is incorrect in my solution?

Comment: @John Edited my answer, again.

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense. But how exactly am I improperly applying the inclusion-exclusion principle? Or do you mean that I am not supposed to use it to begin with in this problem?

Comment: @John Suppose that given a set $E$, with a finite number of elements, that $|E|$ denotes the number of elements in the set $E$.  Then, by Inclusion-Exclusion, $$|R\cup S| = |R| + |S| - |R\cap S|.$$  This analogizes to what you did, and it represents, counting $|R\cap S|$ twice, and then deducting it once.  By analogy, this parallels your computation.

Comment: Ah, and $R \cup S$ is not what I want to calculate, right?

Comment: @John Yes, that's right, $|R \cup S|$ is not what you want to calculate.